# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}} (\frac{\sin x}{1-\sin x})^{\frac{1}{1-\sin x}}$

Tags: limits

Let $\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}} (\frac{\sin x}{1-\sin x})^{\frac{1}{1-\sin x}}=L$ 
$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{1}{1-\sin x}\ln (\frac{\sin x}{1-\sin x})}=\ln L$ 
$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2\sin x}{(1-\sin x)^2}=\ln(L)$ 
$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2\sin x}{x}\cdot\frac{x}{(1-\sin x)^2}=\ln(L)$ 
$undefined=\ln{L}$ 
Thus L=undefined?

Comment: What has happened in the third line where the $\ln$ disappeared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit is $+\infty$.

exponent: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{1-\sin x}\right)=+\infty$.

base: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\sin x}{1-\sin x}\right)=+\infty$.

Thus, you have $(+\infty)^{+\infty}$. It's not indeterminate, but $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin x$ is just below $1$, so $1-\sin x$ is just above zero.
So $\frac{\sin x}{1-\sin x}$ is a  large positive number.
$\frac1{1-\sin x}$ is another large, positive number.
So your expression is a very large positive number.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}} (\frac{\sin x}{1-\sin x})^{\frac{1}{1-\sin x}}
\\&=\lim _{t\to 0}\:\left(\frac{\sin \:\left(t+\frac{\pi \:}{2}\right)}{1-\sin \:\left(t+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\sin \:\left(t+\frac{\pi \:}{2}\right)}}
\\&=\lim _{t\to 0}\:\left(\frac{cos\left(t\right)}{1-cos\left(t\right)}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-cos\left(t\right)}}
\end{aligned}$$
Then:
$$
\lim _{t\to 0}\left(\frac{ln\left(\frac{cos\left(t\right)}{1-cos\left(t\right)}\right)}{1-cos\left(t\right)}\right)
=\lim _{t\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{1-\cos(t)}\cdot \left(\:ln\left(\cos(t)\right)-ln\left(1-\cos(t)\right)\right)\right)=\infty$$
So

$$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}} (\frac{\sin x}{1-\sin x})^{\frac{1}{1-\sin x}}= e^\infty= \color{red}{\infty}$$